# Can't solve differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I tried making this substitution using what I know about the homogeneity of this ODE:
[image]

Friend,where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

The sustitution $x=vy,\;dx=vdy+ydv\,$ give us
\begin{align*}
&&-y(vdy+ydv)+\left(vy+\sqrt{vy^2}\right)dy&=0\\
\iff&& -y^2dv+\sqrt{vy^2}dy&=0
\end{align*}
Now, let's suppose $y> 0$ and $v>0$, then we get
$$-y^2dv+y\sqrt v\, dy=0$$
And then
$$\dfrac{dy}{y}=\dfrac{dv}{v^{1/2}}$$

Comment: but where did I go wrong?

Comment: Usually an homogeneous DE can be solved by sustitution $y=ux$ or $x=vy$, while you are trying to make $xy=v$, which seems doesn't work.

Comment: is this only conditional? for y and v greater than 0?

Comment: Assumptions about $y$ and $v$ are made in order to perform operations, although the solution can be defined for $y\le 0$ and $x\le 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Integrating factor is
$$\mu=\frac{1}{xP+yQ}=\frac{1}{x(-y)+y(\sqrt{xy}+x)}=\frac{1}{y\sqrt{xy}}$$
Then solution of differential equation $-ydx+(x+\sqrt{xy})dy=0$ is
$$\log{(y)}-2 \sqrt{\frac{x}{y}}=C$$